# Sending POST data from Symfony into Yii controller

Tags: php, symfony, yii

I have Yii2 project. And there I also have api written by Symfony.
In Symfony part I have method in the class which send request to Yii controller.

```
    $buzz = $this->container->get('buzz');
    $buzz->getClient()->setVerifyHost(false);
    $buzz->getClient()->setVerifyPeer(false);
    $buzz->getClient()->setTimeOut(false);
    $url = $this->container->getParameter('integra_sync_prices');

    $sendResult = $buzz->post($url, array('authorization' => $this->container->getParameter('load_token')), array('products' => 
    json_encode($productPrices)));
    $resultJson = json_decode($sendResult->getContent(), true);

    if (isset($resultJson['error']))
        throw new \Exception('Site: '.$resultJson['error'], 500);
```

```
class IntegraController extends Controller{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $headers = Yii::$app->request->getHeaders();

    foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
        if(strtolower(trim($key)) == 'authorization') {
            $token = trim($value[0]);
            break;
        }
    }

    $products = json_decode(Yii::$app->request->post('products'));
    $post_products = Yii::$app->request->post('products');
    if('111' == $token) {

        if(isset($post_products) && $products) {
            foreach ($products as $product) {

                echo $product->price." = ".$product->productId."<br>";

                Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE oc_product SET quantity = '" . (int)$product->quantity . "', price = '" . (float)$product->price . "' WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product->productId . "'")->execute();
            }
            $json['success'] = 'complete';
        } else {
            $json['error'] = 'empty data';
        }
    } else {
        $json['error'] = 'authorization error';
    }

    Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    echo json_encode($json);
    }
```

I expect that data in my database will be updated by this controller. But there in nothing changes.
What do I do wrong? Maybe I should send some another headers? Thanks a lot )

Comment: Dump some values in the chain to check where it breaks. Or do you get any of the errors/exceptions?

Comment: If I try to get var_dump() of request UI receive error 400 bad request of server

Comment: Sorry, response